# How to save data to local storage and then have it persist on page reload, i have added a local storage function but it doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, momentjs

I'm building a work day scheduler and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to save data inside the schedule event (eg: 8am) and then have it persist on reload, I have already got the coloured time block element(changes colour as hours in the day pass) sorted out. I just need help on how I can save the data inside the time block.

```js
const clock = document.getElementById("clock");
 setInterval(() => {
    const now = moment();
    const readable =now.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
    clock.textContent = readable;

 }, 1000);

 $(document).ready(function(){

var scheduleContent = [];
var getLocalStorageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("schedule-items"));

if (getLocalStorageData !== null) {
    scheduleContent = getLocalStorageData;
}

   $("button").on("click", function() {
    var container = $(this).parent().parent();
    var inputValue = container.find("input").val();
    var inputId = container.find("input").attr("id");
    var textObj = {
        "input-id": inputId,
        "input-value": inputValue
    };

    if (textObj["input-value"] !== "") {
        scheduleContent.push(textObj);
        localStorage.setItem("schedule-items", JSON.stringify(scheduleContent));
    }
});





    var elements = $(".time-block");
    var d = new Date();
   var h = d.getHours();
   
    
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var t = parseInt(elements[i].getAttribute("data-hour"));

        if (h < t) {
            elements[i].classList.add('future');
            elements[i].classList.remove('past');
            elements[i].classList.remove('present');
        }  else if (h > t) {
            elements[i].classList.add('past');
            elements[i].classList.remove('future');
            elements[i].classList.remove('present');
        } else if (h === t) {
            elements[i].classList.add('present');
            elements[i].classList.remove('future');
            elements[i].classList.remove('past');
        } else if (h > 16 && h < 9) {
            elements[i].classList.add('future');
            elements[i].classList.remove('past');
            elements[i].classList.remove('present');
        }
    }

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
}

textarea {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.description {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.time-block {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.row {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 80px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.hour {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000000;
}

.past {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: white;
}

.present {
  background-color: #ff6961;
  color: white;
}

.future {
  background-color: #77dd77;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #06aed5;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn i:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css" />
  <title>Work Day Scheduler</title>
  <header class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3">Work Day Scheduler</h1>
    <p class="lead">A simple calendar app for scheduling your work day</p>
    <p id="currentDay" class="lead"></p>
    <div id="clock"></div>
  </header>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
  <!-- Timeblocks go here -->

  <div id ="hour-1" data-hour="8" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-1 hour">
      8AM
    </div>
    <textarea id ="8AM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-2" data-hour="9" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      9AM
    </div>
    <textarea id="9AM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-3" data-hour="10" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      10AM
    </div>
    <textarea id="10AM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-4" data-hour="11" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      11AM
    </div>
    <textarea id ="11AM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-5" data-hour="12" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      12PM
    </div>
    <textarea id ="12PM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-6" data-hour="13" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      1PM
    </div>
    <textarea id="1PM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-7" data-hour="14" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      2PM
    </div>
    <textarea id="2PM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-8" data-hour="15" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      3PM
    </div>
    <textarea id="3PM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-9" data-hour="16" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      4PM
    </div>
    <textarea id="4PM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-10" data-hour="17" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      5PM
    </div>
    <textarea id="5PM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/how-to-store-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Web Storage API (Window.localStorage or Window.sessionStorage). Check out this article on html5doctor for a more in-depth explanation. The Web Storage API is supported by all modern browsers at this point.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).